# Words in letters $x,y,z$ such that maximal sequences of $x$'s and of $y$'s are even (recurrence relations)

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

I'm supposed to solve the following problem.

What's the number $F(n)$ of words with $n$ letters using the alphabet $x,y,z$ such that maximal sequences of $x$'s are of even length, and the same for $y$'s? (For instance, $zxxxxzyy$ is legal but not $zxxxzzyy$.)

I just tried to split into cases:

1. If the first letter is $z$, then we omit the first letter and move to $F(n-1)$
2. If the first letter is $x$ or $y$, omit the first two and move to $F(n-2)$.

This gives me the following recurrence relation to solve $$F(n)=F(n-1)+2F(n-2).$$

Is this correct?

Comment: In the second case, what do you mean under "omit the first two"?
The first two letters in the longest sequence, in any sequence or what?

Comment: @HeatTheIce by "omit" I just mean that if the first letter is $x$ or $y$, so must be the second, so we can start over again by looking a shorter sequence of length $n-2$.

Comment: Well, the maximal sequence should be even so what if you have a sequence like xzxxxzxxxx. Here you can take just the first x away, and it will still follow the rule.

Comment: @HeatTheIce I don't understand - the sequence you wrote doesn't follow any rule...

Comment: @HeatTheIce: You’ve misunderstood the question, I think: it appears that the OP means that *each* maximal block of $x$s has even length, and the same for $y$s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the analysis is correct, as is the recurrence, but you should add the initial conditions $F(0)=F(1)=1$.

By the way, if you then calculate a few values, you can easily find a nicer recurrence:

$$\begin{array}{rcc}
n:&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7\\
F(n):&1&1&3&5&11&21&43&85
\end{array}$$

If you look at the second line, especially the righthand end of it, you’ll see that $F(n+1)$ is approximately $2F(n)$ for each $n$. In fact, it appears to alternate between $2F(n)-1$ when $n$ is even and $2F(n)+1$ when $n$ is odd. If that’s true, we have a first-order recurrence

$$F(n+1)=2F(n)-(-1)^n\tag{1}$$

with $F(0)=1$ for the initial condition. This doesn’t seem to have a nice, straightforward combinatorial explanation, but the second-order recurrence that you found implies that

$$F(n+1)-2F(n)=2F(n-1)-F(n)=-\big(F(n)-2F(n-1)\big)$$

for each $n\ge 0$, and $F(1)-2F(0)=-1=-(-1)^0$, from which $(1)$ follows at once by induction on $n$.